# Jquery - On Scroll change content of a div with animation (waypoint js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I was trying to make something similar to [this site](http://www.kryptis.com/) (service section)
I almost achieved the basic functionality by using waypoint.js but unable to make transition animation i.e. controlled with scroll.
I tried doing this jquery fadeout and fadein but that makes sometime if we scroll fast, waypoint event not triggering.
You can view my code (friddle) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjbblore/07scs10a/2/)

```
var $fixe = $('.fixe');
var $one = $('.one');
var $two = $('.two');
var $three = $('.three');
var $four = $('.four');
var $end = $('.dummy');


$fixe.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $fixe.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        $fixe.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
$one.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $('p').text("This is a test ONE");
        $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+TWO&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
    else {
         $('p').text("This is a test ZERO");
         $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+ONE&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
});

$two.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $('p').text("This is a test TWO");
        $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+THREE&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
    else {
         $('p').text("This is a test ONE");
         $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+TWO&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
});
$three.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
       $('p').text("This is a test THREE");
       $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+FOUR&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
    else {
        $('p').text("This is a test TWO");
        $('img').attr("src","https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=22&txt=Hello+THREE&w=200&h=100&txttrack=0");
    }
});

$end.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $fixe.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
              $fixe.addClass('fixed');

}
}, { offset: '99%' });
```

Also when the last waypoint event triggered the "fixed" class removed which causing big blank space. Is there any way to solve this.